# AngularJs ng-repeat within ng-repeat return same data

Tags: loops, angularjs

I need to perform loop within loop in Angularjs to a directive.
The first looping is getting links from json file and the second loop is looping the data from
previous looped links.

But in the second loop, it returns the same result.

I created a testing [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QXAAIJAzUE3gyy98vLqp?p=preview). You can see what's wrong here.
Thanks

Comment: It actually not return same data, they looping in the same place. How do I separate them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate over jsonLinks you are overwriting $scope.feeds in each iteration. In order to make it work I suggest to replace your loop with: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NfqjdtSDiRW7bGkEWZao?p=preview)

```
angular.forEach($scope.jsonLinks, function(jsonLink) {
    $scope.jsonLink = jsonLink.link;
    dataService.jsonp($scope.jsonLink).then(function(response){
      jsonLink.feeds = response.data.feed;
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, this works but can you put some comments on it?  because i don't understand the `jsonLink.feeds = response.data.feed` and `feed in jsonLink.feeds` in `tpl-1.html`

Answer (score 0):

I had to clear my old answer because it didn't solve the problem. The major issue here is that you are making async calls inside a loop, with no reference to the original jsonLink object where you can store the feeds. You will need a reference to the corresponding parent object for the feed. probably locate it via `id` and then add the feed to it.